# Symfony2 Event Listener preUpdate

Tags: php, symfony, events

I have configured in my **service.yml** some event listener

```
registerproduct.listener:
        class: App\AppBundle\Listener\RegisterProductListener
        arguments: [ @service_container ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

My method **decrementProductQuantity()** works really well when I do a prePersist but not with the preUpdate.

During the update the product quantity decrement well, but there is no changes in the database.

Here is my code for the events:

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->decrementProductQuantity($args);
}

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->decrementProductQuantity($args);
}

public function decrementProductQuantity(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var RegisterProduct $registerProduct */
    $registerProduct = $args->getEntity();

    if (!($registerProduct instanceof RegisterProduct))
        return;

    if ($registerProduct->getStatus() == 'inscription') {
        $product = $registerProduct->getProduct();
        $product->setQuantityStock($product->getQuantityStock() - $registerProduct->getQuantity());
    }
}
```

Here is my update code in my controler:

```
/**
 * @param Register $register
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function confirmAction(Request $request, Register $register)
{
    $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    foreach($register->getRegisterProducts() as $registerProduct){
        $registerProduct->setStatus('inscription');
        $em->persist($registerProduct);
        $em->flush();
    }       
    return $this->redirectWithMode($this->generateUrl('asc_activity_register_show', array('register' => $register->getId())));
}
```

I have no idea why it works when I add something in the database, but not for the update.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not necessary to call "persist" method when you update an entity, because doctrine loads it from db and entity has already been in state "managed".

Comment: Thanks for the highlight

Answer (score 1):

On your preUpdate listener you should to recompute changeset for product entity

```
public function decrementProductQuantity(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var RegisterProduct $registerProduct */
    $registerProduct = $args->getEntity();

    if (!($registerProduct instanceof RegisterProduct))
        return;

    if ($registerProduct->getStatus() == 'inscription') {
        $product = $registerProduct->getProduct();
        $product->setQuantityStock($product->getQuantityStock() - $registerProduct->getQuantity());
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $className = \Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getClass($product);
        $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($classMetadata, $product);
    }
}
```

It happens because in your controller (or somewhere else) your code does not update a product entity. Before listener executing doctrine computes change sets for each entity. Hence in your **preUpdate** listener doctrine does not know anything about product (because it was not changed).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the signature of your preUpdate method:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

/.../

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->decrementProductQuantity($args);
}

/.../
```

Comment: No matter which signature describes the listener method, because PreUpdateEventArgs extends LifecycleEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

Because I didn't find the awnser I finally choose to do it directly in the controller:

```
    /**
     * @param Register $register
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, Register $register)
    {
        $mode = $this->getMode($request);
        $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        foreach ($register->getRegisterProducts() as $registerProduct) {
            if($registerProduct->getStatus() != 'inscription'){
                $product = $registerProduct->getProduct();
                $product->setQuantityStock($product->getQuantityStock() - $registerProduct->getQuantity());
            }

            $registerProduct->setStatus('inscription');
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectWithMode($this->generateUrl('asc_activity_register_show', array('register' => $register->getId())), $mode);
    }
```

If someone find the anwser, please tell me.